# How to save date and time to a specific button?

Tags: android, date, button, time, fragment

I currently have one button to set an alarm. I can save the alarm and the time to this button, but now I want to add another button where I can set another date and time. I don't know how to check which button was clicked and so save the date to this button.
This is what I did it with the alarm button:

I created two classes

 DatePickerFragment.java

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int jahr = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monat = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int tag = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), jahr, monat, tag);
}
}
```

and TimePickerFragmentDialog.java

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
}
```

In my Activity.java I have this code

```
private StringBuilder ausgewaelteDatum;
AlarmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
        }
    });

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    ausgewaelteDatum = new StringBuilder(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format((c.getTime())));


    DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
    timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    ausgewaelteDatum.append(", " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    AlarmButton.setText(ausgewaelteDatum.toString());
}
```

Now I added this code for the second button, but I don't know how to continue. Maybe I could pass the clicked button when I create a new fragment, but I don't know if that's possible

```
DatumButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class MainActivity ... {

    private int clicked = 0;

    private static final int NOBODY = 0;
    private static final int ALARM = 1;
    private static final int DATUM = 2;

    private StringBuilder ausgewaelteDatum;
    private Button AlarmButton, DatumButton; //Consider using standard case notation

    @Override
    ... onCreate(...) {
        AlarmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked = ALARM;
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
            }
        });

        DatumButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked = DATUM;
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        ausgewaelteDatum = new StringBuilder(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format((c.getTime())));

        DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
        timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        ausgewaelteDatum.append(", " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

        if (clicked == ALARM)
            AlarmButton.setText(ausgewaelteDatum.toString());
        else if (clicked == DATUM)
            DatumButton.setText(ausgewaelteDatum.toString());

        clicked = NOBODY;
    }
}
```

If I understood your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I just deleted the `private static final int NOBODY = 0;` line because I don't think it is needed, and it also works without it.